# Переменная в кавычках python

Tags: python

```
cmd = os.system("wp id")

def runWallpaper(self):
        start_enjine = os.system(f"wp run mpv --wid={cmd} test1.wmv --loop=inf --player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui --force-window=yes --no-audio --wid=66442")
```

У меня есть эти строчки, при каждой перезагрузке пк wp id меняется, он нужен для измения обоев, так работает все нормально, но хочется автомотизировать процесс. Чтобы пользователю не приходилось каждый раз его в коде менять. Так вот когда я вставляю переменную в кавычки у меня просто открывается видео плейер, есть другие способы вставить переменную????????

Comment: Извините,а где у вас  _переменная в кавычках_?

Comment: где флаг f стоит в start_enjine=os.system

Comment: Всё равно не понятно. Дайте ссылку на описание комманды mpv, конкретно, что она ожидает в опции  --wid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо вашего

```
cmd = os.system("wp id")
```

примените

```
cmd = 'os.system("wp id")'
```

потому что в фигурных скобках f-стринга не ожидается *результат* команды `os.system("wp id")`, а команда сама.

Comment: Я не понял вопрос, но ответ не понял ещё сильнее. Зачем эту конструкцию подставлять в команду?

Comment: потому при перезагрузке пк id меняется. Нужно постоянно его менять а так все норм

Comment: Эмм... А сразу вставить `start_enjine = os.system(f"wp run mpv --wid=os.system("wp id") test1.wmv...` нельзя???

Comment: Я не понимаю логику вашего ответа. Судя по нагугленной информации, в параметре `--wid` нужно передавать число, которое покажет вызов команды `wp id`. Вы вместо этого числа подставляете команду Python `os.system("wp id")`, и что-то мне подсказывает, что это не сработает. Нужно выполнить команду `wp id`, получить то, что она запишет в stdout, потом это значение передавать как параметр `--wid`.